# Dynamically resize textarea to fit content

Tags: java, swing

Here is a textarea I have put in my program using netbeans. The first image shows what the textarea looks like when I run the program. The second image is show the textarea after I press a button that adds about 50 "Hello world" strings to the text area - only the first 6 get shown. I need the textarea's height to dynamically increase to fit all these strings. Anyone know how to do it?

Edit: I dont want scrollbars so using a JScrollPane is not an option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"I need the textarea's height to dynamically increase"*  Don't do that, simply put it in a `JScrollPane` and scroll to the end when adding new text.

Comment: My program requires that I dont use a scrollpane. I dont want scrollbars on the side of the textareas.

Comment: Does the program require that the text be selectable or editable?

Comment: It needs to be selectable, but not editable. Im now getting the functionality I need using a JLabel so dont need a JTextArea...only issue I have now is the JLabel needs to be selectable on multiple lines - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757914/selectable-jlabel-without-just-a-jtextfield

Comment: should work (given a suitable LayoutManager) - time for an SSCCE to see what's going wrong in your context

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use JTextArea for anything except prototyping. It has the bitter functionality of notepad. But it's up to you.

I would use a JEditorPane or JTextPane. I know you can't size it based on character size but that's for the best. For word wrap, you can do setContentType("text/html"); and wrap the text in <'p><'/p> tags.

(Note you still use JScrollPane for scrolling. In fact, the scroll pane works for any component)

See the differences: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html

I haven't tried it with JTextArea but suppose it should work

Answer (score 1):

Include the JTextArea inside a JScrollPane

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scrollArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

This will dynamically change the text area based on if scrolling is needed or not

Comment: Don't call `setBounds`. Size the text area using the column and row count (in the constructor, or via the public methods), then position the text area using layouts with padding and borders.  If you edit the answer to remove any reference to `setBounds`, I can delete my comment and up-vote.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Just curious why is calling setBounds not recommended here?

Comment: Because of the correct way of doing it which I described immediately after *"Don't call `setBounds`. .."*  If a layout manager is present, bounds will likely be ignored.  And on using no layout manager, see [setLayout(null) is never necessary. Ever!](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374)