# Selectable JLabel, without just a JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent

I need to be able to select the text in a JLabel. Ive read some guides on the net that talk about using a JTextfield to simulate a JLabel, however this is no use to me as I my JLabel will span multiple lines. So any ideas on how to do this or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a non-editable `JTextArea` which allows for multiple lines and selectable text, and visually looks the same as a `JLabel`.

I do not think it is possible with a `JLabel` (at least I do not know how)

Comment: There are other issues to cater for if I use a JTextArea.