# How to make JTexArea fit the window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have created `JTextArea` inserted in `JScrollPane` inside `JPanel` which is inside the `JFrame`.
I had to put exact number of colls and rows in the `JTextArea's` constructor, if didn't the the `JTextArea` was not visible, but when I resize the window the `JTextArea` has fixed size and I don't want it. **I would like it to fix the Window.** How to do it? Thank you.

```
jpMiddle = new JPanel();
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20,42);

JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(
              ta, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                  ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
jpMiddle.add(sp);
```

**EDIT : Figured it out myself:**

```
jpMiddle = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();

JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(
              ta, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                 ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
jpMiddle.add(sp);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757840/dynamically-resize-textarea-to-fit-content

Comment: I cannot believe, 15 minutes ago you were asking about the 'always-visible scrollbars' for your `JScrollPane`, now for the resizing stuff... What's next? At this rate, you're gonna get your whole program from here... RESEARCH FIRST.

Comment: If you figured out yourself, u should post and accept as an answer.